# AngularJS directive called twice fail

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having (probably) a really easy issue, but the thing is that I had spent more time than expected trying to solve it and i haven't done it yet.

My directive in the application is hard to replicate, so, for the purpose of simplicity I made a script in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/DewZb/1/) with a simple directive but with the same result.

Essentially, the problem is related to a directive that have been called twice using different options on each. The result is that the directive rendered always takes the value of the first set of options (and sometimes only with the second set).

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button-menu options="options1" />
    <button-menu options="options2" />
</div>
```

My options (In the controller):

```
// Button Options        
$scope.options1 = {
    id: "1",
    buttonTemplate: "<span style=\"font-size:16pt\">Button 1</span>"
};

$scope.options2 = {
    id: "2",
    buttonTemplate: "<span style=\"font-size:10pt\">Button 2</span>"
};
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, but actually this is the first time that I need a directive running at least twice in a same page, so probably I am missing something.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle that works: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DewZb/4/

First for a weird reason you need a closing tag for button-menu:

```
<button-menu options="options1"></button-menu>
<button-menu options="options2"></button-menu>
```

Create an isolated scope:

```
scope: {options: '='}
```

Then in the link function:

```
scope.buttonOptions = scope.options;
```

Comment: Ha, closing tags... I was having a hell of a time figuring that out.

Comment: A cleaner way would be to use `scope: {buttonOptions: '=options'}` and avoid setting buttonOptions in the link function.

Comment: Yes, nice call. I was doing a similar thing with scope, but it wasn't working. The "weird reason" is that OP was trying to self-close the directive tag, but "custom" tags in HTML 5 are not self-closing, and when you try, you get a "run on" tag. In other words, you get `<button-menu options="options1"><button-menu options="options2"></button-menu></button-menu>`

Comment: And I agree with Roy, that's how I was doing it as well (buttonOptions: '=options'), but I'll give you the +1, since mine didn't work!

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers (Specially to you @andreieib). It was really weird to have the closing tags, but actually I did that and creating the isolated scope and it works flawlessly ! So again, Thank you!

Comment: Fixed all my issues using the closing tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The scope is shared between the same custom directives on the page.  You can setup the directive to have an isolated scope.

The reason you are seeing them take the first or second is because the linking is happening at different times depending on how the angular compile ordered them.  This is because they both have the same priority.

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html